# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); conflicting with Mean-seo

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean, meanjs

I am trying to implement Mean-seo and it seems to be working except every time it redirects to home page.

http://localhost:3333/?_escaped_fragment_=/contact-us
flashes the contact-us page then redirects to home page.

If I remove

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

It shows the contact us page but then the home page is just blank.

Comment: not sure how you get that url generated. Crawlers would be looking at `?_escaped_fragment_=/contact-us`. They take everything after `!` assuming you have proper meta tags

Comment: sorry you are right I had an extra #!/ on the end removed that now.

Comment: when you say proper meta tags I assume you are referring to  `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

Comment: yes regarding meta, but they also include the first `/` which you don't show either. Angular also puts that leading `/` on default page. Then when the `_escaped_fragment_ ` value is simply that slash backend should serve the home page

Comment: tried that.  Now it is `<meta name="fragment" content="!/">` but it still adds #!/ on the end and goes to the home page

Comment: no, not in meta tag...crawlers use everything after the hashprefix `!` as value for the fragment and that value includes the `/` as i showed in my first comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84850/discussion-between-leo-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to solve the problem for me.  using this

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
       //what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
        var path = $location.absUrl();
        if (path.indexOf('_escaped_fragment_') === -1) {
            //instead of returning a new url string, I'll just change the $location.path directly so I don't have to worry about constructing a new url string and so a new state change is not triggered
            return '/';
        }
        // because we've returned nothing, no state change occurs
    });
```

instead of

> $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');